# Solving Within InverseCDF

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following input data:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
x = 5/30 // N; 
y = 0.8;
μ = 0.2;
T = 5;
ρ = 0.8; 
σ (*to be determined*)
```

And this is the given equation:

```
Solve[CDF[
   NormalDistribution[], ((1/
       Sqrt[ρ])*(((Sqrt[1 - ρ])*(InverseCDF[
           NormalDistribution[], (x)]) + (InverseCDF[
          NormalDistribution[], (CDF[
            NormalDistribution[], -(Log[y] + (μ - 0.5*σ^2)*
                 T)/(σ*Sqrt[T])])]))))] == 0.0158854, σ,
  InverseFunctions -> True]
```

If I want to Solve for "ρ" it works, but whenever I try to Solve for σ i get the following error message:

> "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the 
>   system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present 
>   in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact 
>   input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help. >>"

Is here the problem that sigma is simultanously in both an inverseCDF and a CDF?

is there a formula which can be applied in order to get rid of the CDF and inverseCDF?

Or should it be done by splitting up the given equation?

Can anybody help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please try using `FindRoot` rather than `Solve` or, if what you have is some standard derivative, you could use `FinancialDerivative` to calculate the `"ImpliedVolatility"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is helpful to have a look at the output if you just enter your function :

```
CDF[NormalDistribution[], ((1/
 Sqrt[ρ])*(((Sqrt[1 - ρ])*(InverseCDF[
     NormalDistribution[], (x)]) + (InverseCDF[
    NormalDistribution[], (CDF[
      NormalDistribution[], -(Log[y] + (μ - 1/2*σ^2)*
           bigT)/(σ*Sqrt[bigT])])]))))]
(* ConditionalExpression[
     1/2 Erfc[-((-Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - ρ] InverseErfc[2 x] - 
      Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[Erfc[-((-bigT (μ - σ^2/2) - Log[y])/(
      Sqrt[2] Sqrt[bigT] σ))]])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[ρ]))], 
   0 <= Erfc[-((-bigT (μ - σ^2/2) - Log[y])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[bigT] σ))] <= 2 && 0 <= x <= 1] 
*)
```

The first constraint is always met (you can check by plotting it), the second is met in our case. `σ` appears inside the combination `InverseErfc[Erfc[...]]` which I didn't manage to simplify honestly so I used brute force. At this point `Solve` will work, giving two solutions; the second is the positive one.

```
sol[x_, y_, μ_, bigT_, ρ_, v_] = 
Solve[(FullSimplify[
   1/2 Erfc[-((-Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - ρ] InverseErfc[2 x] - 
       Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[Erfc[-((-bigT (μ - 1/2 σ^2) - Log[y])/(
           Sqrt[2] Sqrt[bigT] σ))]])/(
      Sqrt[2] Sqrt[ρ]))] ] /. InverseErfc[Erfc[z_]] -> z) ==
 v, σ, InverseFunctions -> True][[All, 1, 2]];
```

We can check versus a numeric approach :

```
f[x_, y_, μ_, bigT_, ρ_, σ_] = 
 1/2 Erfc[-((-Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - ρ] InverseErfc[2 x] - 
 Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[Erfc[-((-bigT (μ - 1/2 σ^2) - Log[y])/(
   Sqrt[2] Sqrt[bigT] σ))]])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[ρ]))]

output = {#, 
 FindRoot[
  f[5/30, 0.8, 0.2, 5, 0.8, σ] == #, {σ, 0.1}][[1, 2]]} & /@ 
      Range[10^(-3), 0.5, 10^(-2)] ;

Show[ListPlot[output, PlotStyle -> Red], 
     Plot[sol[5/30, 0.8, 0.2, 5, 0.8, v][[2]], {v, 0, 0.5}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: @ b.gatessucks thank you, I have one more question. I am not sure, if I have understand it totally. If I fix v to be i.e. v=0.88, what exactly do I have to enter into output to get the right σ? In other words, if I do not want to see σ and v within a range but to get a nummerical output. I replaced "output" ==# by ==0.88 but I do not think that the result is correct. Could you give me please a hint? thank you

Comment: You can use `sol[5/30, 0.8, 0.2, 5, 0.8, 0.88]` (and take the second solution) or you can use `FindRoot[f[5/30, 0.8, 0.2, 5, 0.8, \[Sigma]] == 0.88, {\[Sigma], 0.5}]` (notice you need to adjust the starting value). Alternatively you can use a different method with `FindRoot[f[5/30, 0.8, 0.2, 5, 0.8, \[Sigma]] == 0.88, {\[Sigma], 0.1, 
  0.01, 2}]`.

Comment: @ b.gatessucks Thanks, I am still a little bit confisued, 0.88 constitutes a probability and in order to determine this probability I entered the following: probability = 
 CDF[NormalDistribution[], ((1/
      Sqrt[\[Rho]])*(((Sqrt[
         1 - \[Rho]])*(InverseCDF[
          NormalDistribution[], (x)]) + (InverseCDF[
         NormalDistribution[], (CDF[
           NormalDistribution[], +(Log[y] + (\[Mu] - 0.5*\[Sigma]x^2)*
                bigT)/(\[Sigma]x*Sqrt[bigT])])]))))] ... whereas σx=0.2 ... so I geht around 0.886. and when I use sol[5/30, 0.8, 0.2, 5, 0.8, 0.886] i get  σ=1.55..?

Comment: @ b.gatessucks that cannot be true, do I have a mistake here? I am confused, because if I assume that σx=0.2  and I determine a probability of 0.886 and if I use sol[5/30, 0.8, 0.2, 5, 0.8, 0.88], I get that  σ=1.55, but it should also be 0.2. thank you for your feedback and help

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `1/2 Erfc[-((-Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - \[Rho]] InverseErfc[2 x] - 
        Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[
          Erfc[-((-bigT (\[Mu] - 1/2 \[Sigma]^2) - 
                Log[y])/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[bigT] \[Sigma]))]])/(Sqrt[
         2] Sqrt[\[Rho]]))] /. {x -> 5/30, y -> 0.8, \[Mu] -> 0.2, 
  bigT -> 5, \[Rho] -> 0.8, \[Sigma] -> 1.53005}` gives `0.88` which agrees with `sol[5/30, 0.8, 0.2, 5, 0.8, 0.88]`.

Comment: @ b.gatessucks ok. I use this function to determine a probability: probability = CDF[NormalDistribution[], ((1/ Sqrt[[Rho]])*(((Sqrt[ 1 - [Rho]])*(InverseCDF[ NormalDistribution[], (x)]) + (InverseCDF[ NormalDistribution[], (CDF[ NormalDistribution[], +(Log[y] + ([Mu] - 0.5*[Sigma]x^2)* bigT)/([Sigma]x*Sqrt[bigT])])]))))] so I get that the probability =0.886. but when I use your suggested funktion and use the same parameter just consider simga the only unknown i get that sigma is 1.55. and not the initial 0.2. so thant the reason why I am confused. do you know what I mean?

Comment: σx=0.2, and when i solve for σ i get 1.55 and not again 0.2, thats what I am confused about.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the left-hand side of the `==`. I changed the greek to roman and removed parentheses that seemed to be redundant, but I can't promise that it's error-free. Then I used three substitutions that are useful in this sort of problem.

```
In[1]:=
(CDF[ NormalDistribution[],
(Sqrt[1-r]*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], x] +
InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[], CDF[NormalDistribution[],
-(Log[y] + (m-s^2/2)*T)/(s*Sqrt[T])] ] )/Sqrt[r]] /.
InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[],p_] -> -Sqrt@2*InverseErfc[2p] //.
CDF[NormalDistribution[],z_] -> Erfc[-z/Sqrt@2]/2 //Simplify) /.
InverseErf[Infinity, -Erfc[z_] ] -> z //InputForm

Out[1]//InputForm=
Erfc[(Sqrt[1 - r]*InverseErf[Infinity, -2*x] +
(m*T - (s^2*T)/2 + Log[y])/(Sqrt[2]*s*Sqrt[T]))/Sqrt[r]]/2
```

Then try taking `InverseErfc` on both sides of the `==` and evaluating with all known values in `N[]` form before giving the problem to `Solve` (or `NSolve`?).